# Configure Tidy for Thymeleaf (Adding <th:block>)

Tags: vim, thymeleaf, tidy, syntastic

**Question:**

How do I allow Tidy to accept this block without errors?

```
<head>  
  <th:block th:replace="foo/fragments/bar :: head"></th:block>
</head>
```

**Background:**

I'm writing html for a project that uses *Thymeleaf* and checking it with *Tidy* via *Syntastic* in *Vim*. This question isn't specific to Vim or Syntastic, that is just how I happen to be invoking Tidy.

**Original error from Tidy:**

```
<th:block> is not recognized!
```

**Attempted Workaround (that doesn't work):**

If I configure Tidy via `--new-blocklevel-tags` which in vim is:

```
let g:syntastic_html_tidy_blocklevel_tags = ['th:block']
```

Then I get the following new error in Tidy.

```
<th:block> isn't allowed in <head> elements
```

Which looks like Tidy is now accepting the Thymeleaf specific block but doesn't like that it is in the head section.